# Sed - Remove digits from end of line/string

Tags: bash, sed, cygwin, gnuwin32

I'm trying to remove digits from the end of each line within a text file, I've tried using:

```
sed 's/[0-9]\+$//' <input.txt >output.txt
```

but it doesn't work, however if I a echo input, ie

```
echo "Bla1Bla123" | sed 's/[0-9]\+$//'
```

it will work correctly and output as expected

```
Bla1Bla
```

removing " 123 " from the end.

however when I try using input.txt it fails to do that for each line..

example of input.txt is

```
heyexample1:123example123
h123h:i123i123
```

which should then output

```
heyexample1:123example
h123h:i123i
```

instead it makes no alterations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your files are probably encoded with the `\r\n` line endings (since you are on Windows). Try `'s/[0-9]\+\r$/\r/'` replace command (preserving the `\r` intentionally).

There might be a way for sed to handle CRLF line endings, but I cannot find it after a brief search.